# UIImagePickerController stuck on dismiss

Tags: iphone, xcode

This is my code:

```
-(IBAction)addUserChooseImage:(id)sender{    
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:     (UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    uploadedImage.image = image;
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

It sticks when trying to dismiss the picker. I believe the reason is that the image picker is activated by a button that sits on a loaded nib view over the viewcontroller itself.

Can anyone tell me what is the right way to dismiss it? I guess the delegate should still refer to self, right?

Thanks

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, i'll make sure to accept relevant answers, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't dismiss picker using the `[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` method.

Replace `[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` with `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Comment: still stuck… It doesn't even show an error msg cause it stops somewhere in the debug code.

Comment: set the scheme to debug mode and put a break point on the method and check is there any logs in the console ?

Comment: What do you mean do the same?

Comment: @user1461635 i just said follow the `Midhun MP` way as he said `set the scheme to debug mode and put a break point on the method and check is there any logs in the console ?`

Comment: @user1461635 i have used your code in my `Xocde`. it's working fine you,if you put some log of the error then we guys can help you better....,please mention clearly whether you are getting this problem on clicking cancel button of `ImagePicker`.

Comment: I don't know how to put the scheme in debug mode, but i ran the app to stop on the bad line. Do you care to see the threads?

Comment: @user1461635 NO need to put scheme here you just debug the code by setting the break point on your above methods...and do all steps and do check what logs you get.

Comment: There is no error msg cause it doesn't crash,it just suddenly show the thread log and stays there.

Comment: @user1461635 come on it...http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19493/dissmissgroup11222

Comment: By the way, i was able to use the code i printed above in another app, but here it doesn't work. I'm pretty sure that this is because I call it from a loaded nib subview.

Comment: Just a try allow all orientation for your application, then check, an mad Idea, but check it please.

Comment: OK, got it. IOS 6 doesn't use dismissModal. It uses dismissViewController. And also i add the next line:

Comment: self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;

Comment: @user1461635: happy to know that your issue is fixed :) Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here you were missing some thing see below

You should use. 
      `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

instead of below.

```
  [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: still stuck… It doesn't even show an error msg cause it stops somewhere in the debug code.

Comment: @user1461635 come on the chat we can solve this here by clicking this link http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19493/dissmissgroup11222

Comment: @user1461635 ok let me know when pickcontroller stuccoed...?on clicking `choose` or `cancel` button.